# How to proceed using Generics in java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, implementation, extends

I have a interface

```
public interface Doable<T,U> {
    public U doStuff(T t);
}
```

I have an abstract class which implements `Doable<T,U>`

```
public abstract class AbstractDoable<T,U> implements Doable<T, U> {
    private SomeClass someClass;

}
```

Now I need to implement the above classes, but I need to use different classes for `T` and `U`.

Please suggest how should I proceed in this as I will need to have multiple implemetations of `AbstractDoable` with different `T` and `U`. For example:

```
ConvertDoable<String,Integer> extends AbstractDoable
```

or

```
ConvertDoable<A,B> extends AbstractDoable
```

Comment: Can I have like this <br/>
public class ConvertDoable<T extends String,U extends Integer> extends AbstractDoable<T, U> {}

Comment: @Gansu: No you can't. Both String and Integer are `final` classes

Comment: @Gansu: Yes, that should work.

Comment: @Bohemian: That doesn't stop you declaring a generic type using the `extends` notation - it's just kinda meaningless in the case of final classes. You might get a compiler warning, but I'd be surprised if it was an error. That said, I haven't tried it myself so I'm happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: @Bohemian, @Cameron ... I will not be using any final classes and that was an example. Please consider `Class1` and `Class2` instead of `String` and `Integer`. But I understand that final classes cannot be used here... thanks for bringing that in

Comment: @Gansu: Final classes *can* be used here. The whole point of generics is that you can use *any* class that meets the type bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create whatever subclasses of `Doable` or `AbstractDoable` you want. For example:

```
public class DoNothing implements Doable<String, String> {
    public String doStuff(String input) {
        return input;
    }
}
```

or

```
public class DoSomething extends AbstractDoable<Integer, String> {
    public String doStuff(Integer i) {
        return i.toString();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what the purpose of your `someClass` member is in `AbstractDoable`. Can you explain what it is for?

Comment: someClass is common for all the implementations, it is sort of helper class that will hold values to complete doStuff method.

Comment: OK. Seems like it doesn't affect the answer, then.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about class bloat, consider anonymous classes - classes defined "on the fly" as you need them:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Doable<String, Integer> myDoable = new AbstractDoable<String, Integer>() {
        public Integer doStuff(String t) {
           return new Integer(t); // for example
        }
    }

    Integer i = myDoable.doStuff("0");
}
```

Comment: I want it to be concrete...Not on the fly then my code would be in a controller and not in the actual implementation...

Comment: @Gansu: This is still concrete. There is a concrete implementation of `AbstractDoable` that just happens to be an anonymous inner class.

Answer (score 1):

Your concrete implementations should either specify the types on `AbstractDoable`

```
public class ConvertDoable extends AbstractDoable<String,Integer>
{
    public Integer doStuff(String arg){...}
}
```

or continue to pass along parameterized generics:

```
public class ConvertDoable<T,U> extends AbstractDoable<T,U>
{
    public U doStuff(T arg){...}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
interface Doable<T,U> {
    public U doStuff(T t);
}

abstract class AbstractDoable<T,U> implements Doable<T, U> {
}

class ConvertDoableStringInteger extends AbstractDoable<String, Integer>{
    public Integer doStuff(String t) {
        return null;
    }   
}

class ConvertDoableIntergerFloat extends AbstractDoable<Integer, Float> {
    public Float doStuff(Integer t) {
        return 0.0f;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea about generics is that you make a single class which supports all types of classes (or at least all classes who inherit from a class or implement an interface).

Also in Java (bytecode) there is no difference between say

```
GenericClass<A,B> foo;
```

and

```
GenericClass<C,D> bar;
```

You thus need to define a single class that can handle all the different objects that might be given to it.